# Execution order of ExceptionFilterAttribute and ExceptionLogger

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET WebApi 2  project and some trouble with the exception handling/logging. Basically in isolation everything works fine, but the order in which they get executed when an error is thrown seems weird to me:

1. `ExceptionLogger` gets called.
2. Filters with `ExceptionFilterAttribute` gets executed.
3. `ExceptionHandler` gets called.

Some of the Exceptions catched via `ExceptionFilterAttribute` are not severe and I want them to be logged at different levels (or not at all; basically I handle them and don't need/want the `ExceptionLogger`, which supposedly is to deal only with unhandled errors). Since the logger gets executed up front, I can't do anything about it.

Is there a way to change this order (to start with the filters) or am I forced to make some workaround (e.g. instead of using `ExceptionLogger` making a filter that does my logging) or is it bad to mix `ExceptionFilterAttribute` and `ExceptionLogger` (and what should I do instead)?